# Why does vb.net Datetimepicker fires a 'GLOBAL WINDOWS HOOK' on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, hook, datetimepicker, keyboard-hook

I have a vb.net Winform Application with a DatetimePicker Control.

Installed 'Zone Alarm' Firewall.

Whenever I Click the Dropdown Button on the Datetimepicker Control, Zone Alarm pops up a message that "This Application is attempting to Monitor User Activities,..etc". 
The Logs in the Zone Alarm says "GLOBAL WINDOWS HOOK" is made.

It alerts in Windows 7 and not in Windows XP.

Why does Datetimepicker attempt for a Global Hook in Windows 7?

[image]

Comment: most of the mouse events and so on use windows hooks

Comment: DateTimePicker is a .NET wrapper for a native Windows component.  Exact same one you see when you click on the clock.  Assuming that there's something wrong with Windows doesn't ever get you anywhere.  ZoneAlarm is the kind of utility that always wants to remind the user that it is Very Important.  Just uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you, But I cannot force a client to uninstall it. Right? ;)